# error KeyError: 'ObjectType' when loading pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, dill

I'm using python 3 on mac.

I have tried to load a pickle into python and i saw an error regarding my "dill" package. after a lot of reading i found a specific version of dill that works for python2 -pip install dill==0.2.7.1.
my question is what version of dill will works for python3?

```
with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
    pi = pickle.load(fp)
```

now,when I'm running the script on python3 I'm getting the error:

```
File "/Users/Yuval/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 546, in _load_type
    return _reverse_typemap[name]
```

`KeyError: 'ObjectType'`

Comment: Are you trying to un-pickle data in Python 3 that was pickled using Python 2? What type of object is in the pickled data?

Comment: this is a svm model that someone trained and saved using python2. i want to load it using python3.

Comment: Newer versions of pickle have more protocols, but they _should_ be able to correctly unpickle data pickled by older versions. I suspect that there's a more subtle incompatibility problem, eg if a pickled object was created by an old version of some 3rd-party library, and that object structure isn't compatible with the new version of that library on your machine.

Comment: ok..tnx for your comment.

Comment: Maybe this is too old but, knowing `dill`, `"ObjectType"` refers to the `object` type-object. You can probably add the missing `ObjectType` entry with `dill._dill._reverse_typemap["ObjectType"] = object`. The current name of this type (at least since Python 2.7) is just `"object"`.